# Reopen closed question: 'Is “Why Steven Sinofsky is out at Microsoft” correct?'

Tags: support, questions, closed-questions

I think that [this is a perfectly good question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91162/is-why-steven-sinofsky-is-out-at-microsoft-correct) and have no idea why it has been closed. The only person to have provided a reason for his/her close-vote as a comment is Fumble. He too has stated that it is "Not Constructive" and yet has voted "Not a real question". Furthermore, the commenters can't make up their mind on why the Ars headline is right either.

Answer (score 1):

I voted against it. I don't recall whether I came down on NC or NARQ - I always have trouble with those two - but I voted against it basically because it's a headline, which to my mind makes any generalization questionable. "Hard cases make bad law" -- as I think your answer makes clear.

Comment: Well, the original question has been re-opened - and you and I have shot our bolt, so we can't closevote again for the time being. But I'm not convinced it matters exactly which reason you choose (assuming we don't create a special closevote reason "Pointless evaluation of 'journalese' syntax").

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are worse questions out there. This one's a misparse -- {SS / out at M} instead of { SS out / at M} -- occasioned by headline scorched-earth ellipsis. If somebody comes up with a procedure for parsing such constructions correctly the question will be justified. I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: I don't think the question was about "misparsing" as such. OP wants ELU to vote for *his* preferred preposition, but as the protracted comment thread clearly showed, you could (perversely or otherwise) misparse it in many different ways with *either* preposition. The possibility that one particular preposition might be (slightly) less susceptible to being misparsed is scarcely relevant to my objections.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes. I think the question *asked* was *occasioned by* a misparsing; the interesting question (which maybe somebody will address in spite of what's asked) is *how do you avoid misparsing*?

Comment: oic. I hadn't thought of it like that. Superficially you'd think really competent speakers should in theory be less likely to misparse, but I sometimes think being consciously aware of more possible ways to parse something might make mistakes *more* likely. I'm hopeless at those "non-cryptic" crosswords with single-word clues, because I often can't find a single clue with one unambiguously correct answer that I dare write in to get started. But people with less "imaginative" vocabularies just write in the first word that comes to mind (which, irritatingly to me, is usually right! :)